# Jar file as agent in java

Tags: java, eclipse, agent, lombok, bootclasspath

When is jar file added as an `agent` in `java` and when it should be added in `bootclasspath` ?

Example :
Why do we add `lombok.jar` as an `agent` when eclipse starts and why also we add in the `bootclasspath` ?

```
 -javaagent:/home/$USER/eclipse/4.4-luna-SR2/lombok.jar
 -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/$USER/eclipse/4.4-luna-SR2/lombok.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in lombok 1.16.x it is no longer necessary to add lombok.jar to the bootclasspath.

Agents live in their own classpath, but share the bootclasspath with the regular program.

Agents typically use instrumentation to modify the bytecode of the classes in your program. If those modifications add calls from your program to code that's only available in the agent's jar, the application classloader and the verifier will resolve those calls against the program's classpath, using the application classloader that in its turn uses the parent classloader, all the way up to the bootclassloader. See the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beadf/index.html) for more information.

Since the agent classloader is not in the parent classloader structure, you cannot call code that's only available in the agent's jar file.

The simplest solution is to add the agent's jar to the bootclasspath, making the code in the agent's jar available for both the agent and the program.

In lombok 1.16.x, a different approach is used. The agent modifies the Eclipse classloader to also look in lombok.jar when resolving classes.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: I'm curious to  know what kind of calls are required from a program using lombok that is only available in lombok.jar ? Also I read here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-lombok/ , http://notatube.blogspot.ie/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html, that lombok does not modify bytecode , instead it transforms the AST. But you have written above that it modifies the bytecode. Can you pls. clarify ?

Comment: We change the bytecode of the Eclipse classes. Oh, and if you use `@SneakyThrows` we also do change a small bit of bytecode, just to [remove the call to Lombok.sneakyThrow](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/bytecode/SneakyThrowsRemover.java#L67).

Comment: Why is it required to change the bytecode of eclipse classes ? Also I had doubt about can lombok changes the line nos. in stacktrace which will result in line nos pointing to wrong info (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908097/line-numbers-generation-with-lombok)

Comment: We change the Eclipse bytecode to invloke lombok after the code has been parsed by the Eclipse parser, and to hook into several CompletionProposal parsers. Regarding the line numbers: We try to set the line numbers to the lines of the annotation responsible for the generated code, so that F3, go to declaration works. In some cases that is unfortunately not possible.