# Line Numbers Generation with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Does using `lombok` in `java` class will result in wrong line numbers in `stacktrace` ?
Assumption : No `delombok` has been used on the code.

Lombok does not interrupt with `line number generation` but it would generate code wherever the annotations are placed. These line nos. would be part of byte code and hence when in `stacktrace` is printed, it would contain wrong line nos. Is my above interpretation correct ?

Answer (score 3):

The line numbers are stored in the `.class` file by the Java compiler based on the actual lines of the `.java` source code file.

Lombok hooks into the compilation process itself, modifying the bytecode that is written into the `.class` file on the fly. It never actually adds text to the `.java` source file and it also does not alter the line number information the compiler stores in the `.class` file.

Therefore, the line numbers in stack traces always match the actual Java source code.

---

<sub>Note: The question ruled out the "delombok" case. For interested readers: you can use the "delombok" plugin to generate plain `.java` code that incorporates everything that Lombok would otherwise put in during compilation. The tool is intended for situations like removing Lombok from a code base, or feeding source code to an analyzer tool that is confused by Lombok stuff. In that case, you end up with different, larger `.java` source files, which of course have different line numbers.</sub>